# AC not shutting of automatically

Tags: hvac, heating, air-conditioning

I recently had new HVAC installed. I am noticing it being little louder than what I had previously. The new system is American Standard 80% efficiency with ECM blower motor. My question is

1. Can I reduce the fan speed to make it little quieter? - I asked the contractor who installed it and he said he can certainly changed the fan speed but there might be and issue that your ac may get icing. So is that true that by reducing fan speed may create icing issue?
2. AC is not Turing off automatically even when temp reached to set point. I have checks that the fan is on auto setting and thermostat shows the set temp. If I increase the set temp to higher than what is currently on display then it shuts off automatically but when it gets to desired temp, it does not shut off automatically.

What could be the issue? Thermostat or faulty wiring?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You say it does not shut off when it reaches the set point. In that case does the temperature go below the set point and keep going lower and lower? Or does it finally shut off 2 deg F or so below the set point? Do you have an advanced system that controls both temp and humidity? If so perhaps the condensing unit goes to a lower refrigerant pumping rate and settles into a steady state maintenance mode to keep the temp at the set point without cycling off and on.

Comment: Let the unit operate without intervention and see how it performs.

Comment: Yep this is exactly what “dead band” is doing to save $.

Comment: @Jim, It stays at set point and temp does not go below the set temp. But what I have noticed more is that it keeps running about 2 hrs and then shuts off for hour or so then turns back on and again runs about 2 hrs. But the set temp and actual temp remains the same through out the cycle. My understanding is that as soon as the actual temp reached the set temp it should immediately turn off.

Comment: So the air handler inside is staying on, but could you check to see if the condensing unit outside is cycling off and on? There are dual compressor condensing units in which (I think) only one compressor runs when the cooling demand is relatively low. These are very quiet and efficient and you will have to look closely to see whether the condensing unit is even on. What is the make and model of your unit? Where is this? I am personally unfamiliar with high efficiency units but a long running air handler is not necessarily a fault condition, it may be a feature.

Comment: @Jim it’s an Amrican STD 4A7A3036H1000NA AC and S8B1D120M5PSAA furnace with ECM motor. The AC unit is outside. So my only thing is that the unit does eventually shut itself after about running for around 2 hrs and set temp was already reached during the cycle. But I am not sure about my thermostat dead ban setting. I want to make sure if there is anything that I should be concerned or not.

Comment: AFIK might be design behavior for this model or it may be a fault. Since it is new and under warranty there is no urgency to do anything. Keep notes on how it performs, but just don't over control it. Set the thermostat and leave it. After the air handler finally shuts off, how long is it off before it comes on again? Is it always on for two hours at a time?

Comment: @Jim. At times at stays off for about hour or so and turns back on. It’s only been 4 days so I will try to mark the the timings. And I think thermostats will not be an issue since I have checked that unit turns off immediately if I raise the temp and even turns off if I manually turn off from it.

Comment: @Jim I observed the run time today. Outside temp was hovering around 70s. My set temp is 74 on thermostat. 
AC turned on at 12.01 pm and turned of at 1.05. Then turned back on 2.09 and turned of at 3.12. Turned on at 4.05 and turned off at 5.32. During all the cycles I noticed  thermostat reading 74 constantly. So I am not sure if I should be concerned about anything now since it looks like it cycles for 1 hr on and 1 hr off.

Comment: Where is this? Outside temps in the 70s and thermostat set at 74 F means the unit should be operating very efficiently, hardly being challenged. What kind of thermostat do you have? Does it indicate what the relative humidity is inside? Is the thermostat a type which enables control of both temperature and humidity?

Comment: Jim, Thank you for your response. I am in Chicago. The thermostat is ProT705. I don't think it has humidity control. As I observed more timings, it looks like it does not run for set time (Hourly cycles). Last night it only ran for 40 min and turned off and this morning it has not turned on yet. Only thing I am worried is why it is running even after set temp is reached (Sometimes well above 20-25 min once the temp reached).
May be am I over concerned? Or good way to see how much my electricity bill comes out comparatively to last one? if it less or similar, I will let it run as is.

Comment: I have investigated specs and features on the condensing unit, air handler-evaporator-furnace and thermostat.  Nothing indicates  that in the cooling mode your air handler should stay on for 20 ,min or more after the set point is reached. The air handler on my much older but similar system runs for about  1 or 2 min after the thermostat signals the condensing unit to turn off. I think this delay must be controlled by a timing module on the main board in the air handler. There may be a tiny jumper on the board that sets this time which is loose or maybe a loose wire from thermostat.

Comment: I do NOT encourage you to DIY possible faults since the system is new. The most I would do in your position would be to make sure to have the thermostat in the "hold" mode rather than programmed and see if the condition persists. Another thing you could do is to put the setpoint at a significantly lower temp like 70 F or even 68 F and see how the unit performs. Does it cool down to that and how long does the air handler stay on after the set point is reached? I mean this as a test. I am NOT suggesting that you would have to leave the setpoint at 70 F for it to work properly.

Comment: I mean put the thermostat in the "permanent hold" mode. Then change the setpoint with the + and - buttons.

Comment: @Jim, I am anyhow upgrading to smart thermostat so let me see if the new thermostat resolves the issue. And I will also try to lower the temp few degree Like you suggested and see how it works.

Comment: The ProT705 seems like a good programmable thermostat.  Maybe you should get the system working properly before you change.

Comment: @jim I was going through manual and found Wiring diagram. On this diagram there are some timing mentioned.One of them being Auto Restart: 60 min. Could this be the reason why the unit almost kicks on after one hour?
Here are different timings listed
Prepurge: 0 sec
Interprurge: 60 Sec
Postpurge: 5 sec
IGN Warmup: 20 sec
IAP:3; TFI: 5 sec
Retried: 2 Recycles: 10
G=Heat one delay: Up to 30 sec
Cool on Delay: 0 sec
**_Auto Restart: 60 Min_**
Auto Restart Purge: 60 Sec
I kept asking the contractor to take a look and he keeps on insisting new thermostat. may be time for second opinion.

Comment: I am not the person to ask about trouble shooting this, but I see no reason to get a second opinion yet. If the original installer has a reasonably good reputation then I would stick with them for the time being. If the outside temp is almost the same as the setpoint, then the compressor may not be running long enough to reach a steady state. Set the thermostat to 70 F and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

If the evaporator will ice up depends on the type of control if it is orifice or capillary tube control it may Ice up but if a thermal expansion valve called TXV this regulates the flow and it should not but I have seen TXV controlled system ice up a few times.
As far as your system not shutting off when the temp is reached this is to keep the system from short cycling there is a setting sometimes called “dead band” usually around 3 degrees and is set in your thermostat it may be a setting like +2 -2 this would be a 4 degree dead band or the thermostat won’t turn the heat on until 2 degrees below set point and won’t shut off until 2 over set point same with the ac, you can usually change these I change mine based on season +0 -2 is my summer setting and +2 -0 is my winter setting. If it takes 10 minutes to change 1 degree a 2 degree dead band is ok but if you reduce it two far your energy cost will go up and the life of your system may be reduced from the repeated startups.

Comment: You know,changing the dead zone like that is no different than changing the sticker on your amp’s volume knob so it goes to 11 lol.

Comment: Not exactly it tells the thermostat when to turn on and off. I have set it to 0 +- yes it turns on and off with the settings but is hard on an hvac system , like a heat pump never shut down going from heating to cooling in 1 minute. Yep tried it , saw my electric bill jump 100+ a month but the temp was right there. , bump it by 2 to 4 and save 100 or more on peak months both summer and winter.

Comment: @ed so you suggest having and dead band of around +_ 2 is good in terms of saving some $$$ as well as performance of the unit?

Comment: Yes this allows the unit to run with fewer startups, ac compressors draw a substantial amount on startup so by having a dead band it runs a little longer Getting slightly cooler than the set point and turns on just above for a 4 degree swing on my 5 ton unit that was 100$ per month difference I don’t remember what it was +0 -2 or 2 degree swing it was not a straight comparison I think it was 65 or 70$ less than 0 dead band my wife noticed the 4 degree swing but was fine with 2. I started this when I adjusted my trunk dampers to push more air upstairs in summer and down in winter.

Answer (score 0):

What I get from searching on your model is that your condensing unit is a basic single compressor model with a modest SEER of 14 or 16 depending on which evaporator and air handler it's paired with so I doubt you have a variable speed compressor, although you might have a two speed condensing fan.

However, your air handler inside is described as having a variable speed motor. This could mean it is continuously variable in a range during cooling or just has two speeds in which a higher speed is used for a/c and a lower speed is used for heating. Can you tell if the fan is varying in speed? Is it louder sometimes and quieter others?

The long run time of your air handler after setpoint is reached is unusual in my experience but could be a feature of this type of air handler. For the time being I suggest you just use it without over controlling, but keep records on how long the air handler is running.

Comment: I have to check on variable speed. But like I mentioned earlier that it runs for hour and then shut off for hours and then again runs for hour. So not sure if anything is wrong or I am just over thinking.

Comment: Sorry I take my words back about it running for constant 1 hr. Because last night it ran for 45 min and then turned off. Since this is only 5-6 day old in my house I am still discovering lot of things about it. I guess I did not pay this much attention to my older unit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks for taking time answering my question.

I upgraded to new thermostat and now my AC cycles fine. (10-15 min on avg hot day).

Comment: Thanks for coming back. Would you add a bit more info to your answer (e.g. new thermostat make/model)? Then you could accept your answer as the best for your question.